# Throwing Fatal Error after trying to Login in WordPress project

Tags: wordpress, fatal-error

When i try to login in my project and i got the following exceptions:

> Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Cannot create references to/from string
>   offsets in
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\wordpress\group-delphi-museums\wp-includes\user.php on
>   line 56
>
> Error: Cannot create references to/from string offsets in
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\wordpress\group-delphi-museums\wp-includes\user.php on
>   line 56

Any ideas ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

can you provide more information please? When did it happen? themes, plugins that may be affecting it. Most likely its a theme issue, if you log into your server or cpannell navigate to /wp-content/themes and delete your theme. Then reinstall 2017 theme, deactavate all your plugins, re-install your theme and use a process of elimination through your plugins to find out the error. If you were editing your theme, you probably just broke it thus no issue with your plugins. It should be sorted then.

Comment: I'm trying to setup project. When i setup it in other laptop, it's running correctly, but in my machine cannot